# Tokenizer - Initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

Tags: c++

I'm working on creating a program that will take a fraction and reduce it to it's lowest terms. I'm using a tokenizer to parse through the string (In my case I'm reading in a string) and separate the numerator from the denominator.

I'm getting the following error, and am looking for an explanation to why it's happening. I've looked up people with similar problems, but I'm still a beginner looking for a basic explanation and suggestion for an alternative way to solve it.

```
RationalNum() // Default
    :numerator(0), denominator(1){}
RationalNum(int num) // Whole Number
    :numerator(num), denominator(1){}
RationalNum(int num, int denom) // Fractional Number
    :numerator(num), denominator(denom){}
RationalNum(string s)
{
    int num = 0;
    char str[] = s;
}
```

I know the problem lies in the setting the char array to s.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: if `string` is a `std::string` use `s.c_str()` to get a `const char*` from it. That's about equivalent to a `char[]`, but const. If you need non-`const` access you *need* to copy the string (e.g. `strdup`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialise an array of char to a std::string, which is an object. The literal meaning of the error is that the compiler is expecting an initialisation that looks something like this :

```
char str[] = {'1','2','3','4'};
```

However, since you are planning on string manipulation anyway, you would have a much easier time just keeping the string object rather than trying to assign it to a char array.

Instead of building your parser from scratch, you can use [string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). with '/' as your delimiter. You can initialise an std::stringstream with a string by passing it as an argument when constructing it. You can also use another stringstream to convert a string into a number by using the [>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) operator.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I do appreciate your response! We did an example in class a few days ago that did provide a sample string (ex "Hello, World!", how every I know the fraction is depending on the user's input. I know the stl tokeniser uses a "hard-coded" array, and I'm not sure how to use the string stream.

Once again sorry if this seems extremely basic, but I'm a complete novice when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: @mike112, ok, I've edited my answer. I've provided links for getline which shows an example of how to use it with your own delimiter. The stl tokeniser doesn't only take hardcoded strings, it takes a char * ( character pointer ), which is the same type as hardcoded strings, but they can also be built dynamically. In fact you could 'substitute' char *'s with char[]'s. However, stringstream is more useful overall, so I've removed strtok as a suggestion.